# How does css class selector (.class-name) work in combination with css tag selector (div, etc...)

Tags: html, css, reactjs

In my website I have created three separate tables that should all have slightly different styling.  In general I apply my styling to the tables as follows:

```
import './gameview.css'
<div className="game-results">
        <h5>Results:</h5>
        <table>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Name</th>
              <th>Cash in</th>
              <th>Cash out</th>
              <th>Balance</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            {game.results.map(result => (<TableRow key = {result._id} result = {result}/>))}
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
```

I have a table within a div that has a class name game-results (by the way I'm using React). Then in my CSS file "gameview.css" I target tags within that table as follows:

```
.game-results {
    padding: 0px 12px;
}

.game-results h5 {
    margin-top: 6px;
}

.game-results table {
    font-size: 0.9em;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    margin: 15px 0px;
    padding: 10px;
    
}

.game-results th, td {
    border: 1px solid rgb(57, 56, 56);
    padding: 6px 8px;
}
```

The logic being I don't have to give classnames to all my th, td, tr tags. Then in a completely separate component without even importing "gameview.css" my table elements seem to inherit these css properties even when they are placed in a div with a different className!?

What are the possible reasons these styles are being applied if I'm not importing the css file in that specific component? Also how can I ensure that the css properties will only be applied to the html tags within that container?

Comment: I believe what you'd be thinking of are [module css files](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-a-css-modules-stylesheet/), which isolates css classes from other components by dynamically generating names.

Comment: "In a completely seperate component without importing gameview.css..." Where in your stack the css is imported isn't relevant, only if it is imported or not. Importing css is the equivalent of adding it to a `globals.css`, it applies to your entire HTML once it's imported

Comment: your selector styles **any td** it finds : `.game-results th, td` , to only style td from that peticular table, it should be  `.game-results th, .game-results td` :)

Answer (score -1):

In your provided code, the CSS class selector (.game-results) is used to style the  element with the class "game-results." This selector targets that specific element and applies styles to it. The class selector is independent of the HTML tag selector.

For example, .game-results styles the  with class "game-results," while .game-results h5 targets the  element specifically when it is a descendant of an element with the "game-results" class.

So, the combination of class and tag selectors allows you to apply styles to specific elements with a particular class and, in some cases, narrow down the styling to specific elements within that class.